# How to run JS file from typescript code (Node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

How to run JS file from typescript code (Node js)?
In this case, I need to throw the global scope there, which I assigned

example:

GlobalScope(Ts):

```
globalThis.names = ['Joe', 'Bob', 'John'];
```

JS Script(run in runtime):

```
console.log(names[1]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by running JS code from typescript. Typescript is only for development.

Comment: run USING typescript. sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `require` + throw  global scope

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but I'll try to answer nevertheless.

TypeScript transpiled to JavaScript, means the code you write will be transformed to a JS file that does exactly the same, this file is what you will be executing via node.

If you are asking, if you can use JS and TS files in the same projects: Yes that's also totally valid. You can either compile with the `--allowJs` option (read more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)) or specify this in the `tsconfig.json` file, read more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html))